# R data frame of list of data frame

Tags: r, mongodb, dataframe

I've used R to read some data from a mongo collection using mongolite.
Ideally I'd like to create a data frame but the structure of the data is proving too difficult (due to embedded objects in the mongo doc).

Once I've imported the data into R the `str()` is:

```
List of 9
 $ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  6 variables:
      ..$ QS                : num  488 132 186 905
      ..$ datasection1:'data.frame':    4 obs. of  20 variables:
      .. ..$ field1   : int  8 9 15 7
      .. ..$ field2      : chr  "WH" "WH" "WH" "WH"
      ..$ datasection2      :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  12 variables:
      .. ..$ field3: int  8 9 15 7
      .. ..$ field4   : chr  "wh" "wh" "wh" "wh"
      .. ..$ datasection2a:List of 4
      .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
      .. .. .. ..$ price: num  14.5 14 13
      .. .. .. ..$ size : num  12.3 10.8 19.4
      .. .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
      .. .. .. ..$ price: num  5.6 5.5 5.2
      .. .. .. ..$ size : num  23.6 66.7 21.1
      .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
      .. .. .. ..$ price: num  16 12 11.5
      .. .. .. ..$ size : num  11.1 20.7 23.9
      .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
      .. .. .. ..$ size : num
```

etc.

As you can see there are lists and data frames embedded many times.
I've used `dput(head(df,1))` to get:

```
list(structure(list(QS = c(488.4, 131.639655172414, 186.244444444444, 
905.00726079825), datasection1 = structure(list(field1 = c(8L, 
9L, 15L, 7L), field2 = c("WH", "WH", "WH", "WH"),  datasection2 = structure(list(field3 = c(8L, 9L, 
15L, 7L), field4 = c("wh", "wh", "wh", "wh"), datasection2a = list(structure(list(price = c(14.5, 
    14, 13), size = c(12.35, 10.82, 19.35)), .Names = c("price", 
    "size"), ....
```

I've tried various ways to crack this (rbindlist,melt,unlist) but haven't managed to produce a sensible output.  Bear in mind these attempts are based on other similar topics on stack.  I've only been using R for a few months so those functions above are new to me so I may not have used them correctly.
Ideally I'd like data frame for each of the sections, with the _id retained as a key for matching.

If I run:

```
new_df=df[[1]]$datasection1
```

I get a data frame, which I want, but only for the first document.
If I try and run something like

```
new_df=df$datasection1
```

the code runs but I get an empty data frame.

Comment: Please show the full `dput` of a smaller data instead of `...` as we can't copy/paste and reproduce it.  Also, it would be better to show expected output

Comment: It's unlikely you can make a single data.frame from this data. You have multiple fields of different lengths with some fields having the same name. (What kind of data.frame do you expect?) Better to think of this data as nested-lists. For instance, to access `df[[1]]$QS`, do `df[[1]][[1]]`, which gives `488 132 186 905`. To access `df[[1]]$datasection1$field1`, do `df[[1]][[2]][[1]]`, which gives `8  9 15  7`. And so on...